# stored procedure in 2005 based on date

Tags: sql-server-2005

i can write the stored procedure delete the row in table based on date

```
create proc uspInvoicePaymentsdelete3
@PaymentDate datetime
as
begin
delete from tblInvoicePaymentDetails where PaymentDate=@PaymentDate
end
```

but row not deleted i am sending parameter value is '6/15/2011 3:40:18 PM' but It taking 24hours format in my sql server2005 so no rows are deleted how to change the dates.(table date format and parameter date is same format but stored procedure converting 24 hr format)

```
 delete from tblInvoicePaymentDetails where PaymentDate='6/15/2011 3:40:18 PM'
```

but my requirement is datetime consider secounds also ,

- problem is i am sending parameter date and database date both same but output is no rows deleted what is the problem and how to write the stored procedure

Pls give me correct solution

```
      Name            Date           amount  id
    hemanth 6/15/2011 3:40:18 PM    100 1003
    hemanth 6/15/2011 3:40:42 PM    100 1003
```

Thanking u 
hemanth

Comment: In what way "not working"? Is it simply not deleting, or is it throwing an error message?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have posted. Maybe you are passing in a different datetime value to your SP.

Comment: the date in the db possibly contains milliseconds as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be related to the fact that, as @Andrew has pointed out in his comment to your question, datetime values in your table contain milliseconds also, while you are passing the value that doesn't contain milliseconds.

If that is so, you could change the WHERE clause of you DELETE statement like this:

```
WHERE PaymentDate >= @PaymentDate
  AND PaymentDate < DATEADD(second, 1, @PaymentDate)
```

Note, though, that this may lead to deleting more than one row. For example, you have data as follows:

```
Name    PaymentDate             amount id
------- ----------------------- ------ ----
…       …                       …      …
hemanth 2011-06-15 15:40:18.550 100    1003
hemanth 2011-06-15 15:40:18.987 100    1003
hemanth 2011-06-15 15:40:42.363 100    1003
…       …                       …      …
```

If we ignore milliseconds, then there are two rows here with the same value of `PaymentDate`. Maybe, a situation like this is impossible with your application and so you needn't worry about that. I just wanted to make sure that you were aware that, technically, it could be possible to delete more than one record when you are using an incomplete date/time value as a parameter.

Comment: DATEADD(second, 1, @PaymentDate) is not working pls send me any ans

Comment: @hmk: In what way is it not working, please? Does it produce an error message?

Comment: there is no error messages simply based on amount date all rows(above example) deleted but i have delete one record